# 0 rows inserted - oracle database

Tags: oracle

I searched for similar questions but I couldn't find any solution for my case.

So I have a view, and I want to insert some rows of this view to another table that is in another schema. The table has the same column structure and data types as the view. So I use an insert...select statement. My select statement returns rows but after I execute my insert statement, I get 0 rows inserted output.

```
insert into "USER_1"."MY_TABLE"
SELECT * FROM "USER_2"."MY_VIEW" WHERE My_Condition
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The select alone with the condition return results? Are you getting any error? Are you using commit after? Do you have access to insert into this schema(although it should have thrown an error if not)

Comment: The issue is probably the lack of `commit` after the statement.

Comment: @sagi yes, the select alone with the condition returns rows. no errors are thrown. and the user has access to insert that table.

Comment: And the commit part?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried and it didn't work

Comment: Is there any row level security on the table? Are you trying this from sqlplus or from Java? or any other tools? are you capturing the exceptions thrown? Its possible that the columns do not align up or the data types are different. Just insert the first row that you selected manually, in the same order the columns are selected, using sqlplus or other tools, and you may find the error.

Comment: @ShriramM. I tried on sqlplus and jdeveloper, got the same result. When I try to insert a single row manually, it works. What could this mean?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct data type and the correct number of columns. Because, varchar2 is implicitly converted to number/date based on the format. But if the values/format are different on a different row, during bulk load it might fail. Also check if there are any RLS on the table. It might be inserting, but you're not able to query back, because of Row Level Security on the table.

Comment: @ShriramM. actually, you're right. That was because of some data type differences. There's so much column I didn't see that. Now the statement works. Thanks.